# How can I blur a UITextView so the text appears blurred?

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextview

Using UIKit, I have a UITextView. I would like to blur the view so that the text might look somethings like this: [image: blurred text made illegible but recognizably text]. So that it is recognizably text, but illegible

I have been experimenting with `UIBlurEffect` but the closest I have gotten is the code below, that does not apply any sort of gaussian blur, and instead covers the entire view with a grayish blur.

```swift
    private lazy var textView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = textView.bounds
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        textView.addSubview(blurEffectView)

        return textView
    }()
```

[image: gray blob]

Refactoring into SwiftUI is not an option given the constraints of what I'm working on.

Comment: A `UIVisualEffectView` of type `blurEffect` is the only built-in option that I am aware of. If you don't need it to be "live" you could feed an off-screen rendering of the text view through a Core Image blur filter and then install the resulting image into an image view that you place on top of the text view.

Comment: See this thread for sample code that creates a blurred image from a source image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879847/how-to-use-core-image-apis-to-blur-a-image-looks-just-like-the-uivisualview-ef

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a built-in way to do exactly what you want. You could simulate what you want by adding an image view on top of your text view and populating it with a blurred image of the text view.

That code might look something like this:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  BlurredTextView
//
//  Created by Duncan Champney on 10/11/23.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var blurRadius: Float = 10

    func blur(image: UIImage, withRadius radius: Float) -> UIImage {
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)

        guard var ciImage = CIImage(image: image) else {
            fatalError("Can't create CGImage")
        }
        let imageExtent = ciImage.extent
        
        ciImage = ciImage.clampedToExtent()

        guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur") else {
            fatalError("Can't create filter")
        }
        filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter.setValue(radius, forKey: "inputRadius")
        guard let result = filter.outputImage else {
            fatalError("Can't get blurred image from filter")
        }
        guard let outputCG = context.createCGImage(result, from: imageExtent)
               else {
            fatalError("Can't convert CIImage to CGImage")
        }
        let output = UIImage(cgImage: outputCG)
        return output
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var blurSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var blurView: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // textView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    }

    @IBAction func handleBlurSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        print("In \(#function)")
        if !sender.isOn {
            blurView.isHidden = true
        } else {
            
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: textView.bounds.size)
            let image = renderer.image { (context) in
                var bounds = textView.bounds
                bounds.origin = CGPoint.zero
                textView.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
            }
            blurView.image = blur(image: image, withRadius: blurRadius );
            blurView.isHidden = false
        }
        
        
    }
    
}
```

I created a demo project on Github with the above code. You can download it [**here**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/BlurredTextView).

The results look like this:

[image]

(Adjust your blur radius as desired.)

Comment: That code is meant as a guide and not a drop-in solution. You'll have to adapt it to your needs. I'm working on a version that has a custom BlurringView that manages another view and its blurred image. That might work in your context.

Comment: @ocuke I fixed the link to point to the repo correctly